# Early crashes on Android 13

Tags: java, android, kotlin, crash

I have received a lot of crashes on Android 13, which I can not reproduce.

targetSdkVersion 33

compileSdkVersion 33

I'm using view binding.

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.my/com.app.my.ui.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setDecorPadding(int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3868)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4010)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:111)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2466)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:240)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:351)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8380)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:584)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1013)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setDecorPadding(int, int, int, int)' on a null object reference
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.applyFixedSizeWindow (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1109)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:903)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:763)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:203)
  at com.app.my.ui.activities.MainActivity.initBinding (MainActivity.kt:794)
  at com.app.core.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate (BaseActivity.kt:131)
  at com.app.my.ui.activities.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.kt:262)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8397)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8370)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1403)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3841)
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.my/com.app.my.ui.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AppCompat has already installed itself into the Window
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3822)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8252)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.my/com.app.my.ui.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Window couldn't find content container view
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4169)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

I tryed to reproduce, but not success.
I tryed use window.decorView inside onCreate, as suggested, but crashes still present.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue, it started this release... did you find a solution?

Comment: Same issue, only Huawei devices, only android 10